# How to get last inserted id using the JS api?

Tags: mongodb

Using the javascript api for MongoDB, how do you get the ID of the last inserted object? i.e.

```
obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
db.foo.insert(obj);
```

How do I get the ID for obj?

Answer (score 25):

The people on #mongodb were helpful. The JS API doesn't currently support this, but you can use your own id. To generate a "normal" id, do _id: new ObjectId(). So the example in my question would be:

```
id = new ObjectId();
obj = {a: 1, b: 2, _id: id};
db.foo.insert(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question. Much appreciated!

Comment: in my particular case using node-mongodb-native it was `message._id = new mongodb.ObjectID()`

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
db.collection("venues").insert( {name: "test3", FSid: "test3"}, function( err, ret) {
   console.log( ret )
})
```

it returns

```
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
  ops: [ { name: 'test3', FSid: 'test3', _id: 57cb0a1162cecfe636df6fc1 } ],
  insertedCount: 1,
  insertedIds: [ 57cb0a1162cecfe636df6fc1 ] }
```

So you can get your ids along with all inserted objects through:

```
ret.ops[0]._id
```

or straight

```
ret.insertedIds[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now，the mongo native js api supports this. You can get the last id like this:

```
collection.insert(line, {w : 1}, function(err, inserted) {
  inserted[0]._id
}
```

`insert` sets the _id property on the inserted object, but it looks like you have to wait for the object to return. The best documentation I've found for this is (unfortunately) in the source code:

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/collection.js

Comment: isn't safe deprecated now?  aren't we supposed to be using `journal` or `w` ?

Comment: Can you please link to documentation where we can verify this? Also, what exactly are you saying, that insert modifies line to add the _id? Or is line passed back to the callback?

Comment: You forgot the second argument of the callback function, see [api docs](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#insert).

Answer (score 0):

If you insert the data like this:

```
    var temptodo = new User({
        title: data.todo.text,
        email: socket.handshake.email,
        created_at: Date.now(),
        completed: false,
        sid: socket.handshake.sid
    });
    temptodo.save( function(error, User){

            console.log("this is the id for the new todo. "+User._id);
            console.log('Todo saved in database with sid: '+socket.handshake.sid);
    });
```

Then you can grab the _id like this: console.log("this is the id for the new todo. "+User._id);